# VBA in Access Problem with fields being recognized

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report form for labels.  It worked just fine until I tried to add a test for the presence of a "Special_Label" flag in the table.

I coded `If Me.Special_Label <> Null then`  (and after typing the Sp I got the full name of the field in the dropdown and selected it).  But when I run the report I get a message #2465 "Can't find the field 'Special_Label' referred to in your expression".

I have other "Me."fields in the code and they are printed in the label just fine.

I added a `Me.RecordSource = "tblHomeOwner"` in the report open but that made no difference.  It was actually already in the definition of the report.

Trying to learn more about the error, I put in another field instead of Special_Label and it was not found either.  So I am really curious why the processing of the code entry can list the fields of the table for use, but they cannot be found at run time.

As near as I can tell there are no queries involved in this report.  I can see nothing that would restrict the fields available at run time.

Comment: Cannot directly test for Null in an equality expression, nothing is ever equal to or not equal to null, there is nothing to test against, not even `Null = Null`. Use `If Not IsNull(Me.Special_Label) Then`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice about Null but the message still appears even if I use IsNull for testing.

Comment: What happens with this test for Null? If you need more help, edit question to show code.

Comment: I don't know about the test for Null because I have not gotten past the "field not found".  The program logic is being held hostage by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike forms, depending on event code is in and whether you use dot (Me.) or bang (Me!), report could require field referenced in code to also be placed in a textbox. Without bound textbox, using bang in Load event does not error, dot will; both error in Open event.

Bind a textbox to the field. If you don't want value to show, set textbox Visible property to No.

Comment: Perfect Solution.  Thank you.  Report is now printing the way I want.